# Set a the same dictionary for each Pandas cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple Python dictionary. I'd like to add a new column to a Pandas Dataframe where each row in that column is equal to the dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['A','B','C'])

df['D'] = {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'}
```

Desired output

```
   A  B  C                         D
0  1  2  3  {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'}
1  4  5  6  {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'}
```

The actual output only keeps the keys if the dictionary length equals the row length, otherwise it just errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to construct a list the length of the column, then assign it to the column

```
df['D'] = [{'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'} for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: Use this answer

Comment: I get a marginal difference, ~ 4 microseconds on my machine

Comment: And both have the exact same memory footprint

Comment: May be that my test df is just too small. Using `%prun`, it looks like my method has 3 more function calls, which probably adds up. On the other hand, I'm just a big fan of list comps lol

Comment: I do not recommend 2nd method

Comment: @WeNYoBen is there a specific reason?

Comment: Do this `df.loc[1,'D']['AA']='AAAAAAAAA'` ,and print the df again , you will see why :-)

Comment: Yep. there it is lol. That's the kind of thing that makes a user go `'AAAAAAAA'` when they realize what they've done.

Answer (score 1):

using apply:

```
df['D'] = df['D'].apply(lambda x: {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'})
```

result:

```
0  1  2  3  {u'AA': u'BB', u'CC': u'DD'}
1  4  5  6  {u'AA': u'BB', u'CC': u'DD'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterrows() function to loop over each rows:

```
df['D'] = [{'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'} for i in df.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
 A  B   C                             D
0   1   2   3   {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'}
1   4   5   6   {'AA': 'BB', 'CC': 'DD'}
```